# images2gif not seen by spyder python

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-import, spyder, python-module

I've installed [images2gif](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/images2gif) using the standard:

```
install setup.py install
```

trough the terminal of my mac (os x 10.10.5).
If I type `pip freeze` or `pip list`, I normally get it in the list. If I try to import it, in python 2.7, trough import `images2gif` it works.

The problem comes when I'm on Spyder (2.3.8) and I try to do it, I get:

```
>>> import images2gif
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named images2gif
```

If I type `help('modules')`, it's not in the list. How can I do to import it?

Comment: Are you working on a virtual environment?

Comment: @dunder what does it mean?